# Replace all digits except the last four using regex.

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using regex in javascript and want to replace all the digits in a number except the last four with `'#'`.  I have figured out how to replace all the digits with `'#'`, what do I do to not replace the last four?  Here is my code so far.  `return cc.replace(/[0-9]/g, "#")`

Comment: Is the string of a specific size?

Comment: What if there are less than 4 digits?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

use this pattern

```
\d(?=\d{4})
```

and replace with `#`
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/348)

Comment: damn it you beat me to it :)

Comment: Can you provide the regex to mask everything except area code ?