# How to replace all characters except the last digits

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to replace the `-r` in this Semantic version `2020.7.28-r5` with a single period, but I'm getting this instead `2020.7.28.`.

Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
"2020.7.28-r5" -replace "(-[A-Za-z-][0-9A-Za-z-]*)", "."
```

A specification:

- `r` will always be one or more characters (in this case simply `r`)
- `r` can be any SemVer-legal character (`[0-9A-Za-z-]`)
- `r` will always end in a character, never a digit
- `r` will always be preceded by a hyphen `-`
- The final number (the build number for the day) will always be one or more digits

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35510028) I tried this expression:

```
"(-[A-Za-z-][0-9A-Za-z-]*)(?=\d{4})"
```

But it didn't replace anything.

How can I start with `2020.7.28-The11thFantasticallyCleverUpdateForTheDay11` and end up with `2020.7.28.11`?

Comment: Can you give some concrete examples? Is `r` some placeholder for a bunch of numbers or letters ? Then what is `5` right after it ? Some before and after examples would help.

Comment: And why isn't 'everUpdateForTheDay`11`' deleted since `r can contain any number of numbers and/or characters` and `11` is a number of digits.

Comment: `r` isn't a placeholder. My use of the word contains in the first bulleted description left that unclear. I just fixed it. Basically I'm trying to convert a Semantic version number to a normal version number. `5` is the build number for the day. (I use the current date/build for my version numbers in my CD pipeline.)

Comment: I don't think you have a _grasp_ of what `r` the placeholder is. Since you can't distinguish where the `r` stops and the last number of digits begin. You also don't properly define the allowed character set of `r`. I don't believe you know. I recommend you find the specification of what generates this and use that as a template, otherwise it will fail.

Comment: Example `2020.7.28-90523602536934697843811` what is `r` ? According to your spec its unclear. And according to the answer you've selected, the substitution of this is `2020.7.28.90523602536934697843811`

Comment: Good points, thank you. I've updated the spec accordingly. Do you have further suggestion for improvement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
-replace '-[A-Z][0-9A-Z]*?(\d+)$', '.$1'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OUTDsa/3). Mind that PS regex is case insensitive by default, `[A-Z]` is enough to match all ASCII letters.

**Details**

- `-` - a hyphen
- `[A-Z]` - any ASCII letter
- `[0-9A-Z]*?` - zero or more digits or letters
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 (`$1` refers to this value): one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: @InteXX By itself, it does not mean anything here, `*?` is a lazy/non-greedy quantifier that means *as few as possible*

Comment: @InteXX A variation: `$s -replace '-[A-Z][0-9A-Z-]*?(?=\d+$)', '.'`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OUTDsa/2).

Comment: FWIW, I notice that variation also works with only a single question mark: `-[A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]*(?=\d+$)`. Not sure why that matters, but it works both ways.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for pointing out the extra trailing hyphen. I'm pretty sure that doesn't need to be there. Things seem to work without it.